# VBA Copy module from one workbook to another?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a vba module from one workbook to another using the below code.

```
Dim comp As VBComponent
Set comp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("File")
Workbooks("book2.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents.Add comp
```

For some reason this gives me an error user defined type not defined on the following line:

```
Dim comp As VBComponent
```

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: First, why would you need to _programmatically_ copy a module? Second, use debugger to find our at which line you are getting the error.

Comment: @FDavidov please see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3` via Tools/Reference in the VBA editor.

Alternatively, you can use late binding.

Replace

```
Dim comp As VBComponent
```

by

```
Dim comp As Object
```

And then

```
Set comp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("File")
```

Will work as expected. Somewhat oddly, you don't need to include the reference to invoke `.VBProject` since this is a standard property of a workbook object.

Unfortunately,

```
Workbooks("book2.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents.Add comp
```

won't work as you expect. `.Add` creates a blank component. The argument needs to be a constant which describes the type of component you want to create, which should be `1` for a standard code module. (There are named constants that you can use instead of `1`, but I suspect that those constants won't work without the reference).

You can verify that even without the reference the line:

```
Set target = Workbooks("book2.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
```

(where `target` is declared as `Object` or `Variant`) will succeed in both creating a new module in book2 and establishing a reference to it. This reference can be used to transfer code, but not (AFAIK) everything at once. For that you might need to programmatically export/import, as described in Chip Pearson's [article on scripting the VBE](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx). You could work through that article, using late binding whenever needed.

Comment: I cannot do this since i am using a works computer which locks down access to reference. Is there an alternative way?

Comment: @Bing.Wong See if the edit helps. It should at least get you off the ground.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however i get a error saying programmatic access to vba project is not trusted.

Comment: ok i've managed to resolve this error by telling Excel to trust macros. But now i get an error saying Subscript out of range on the 2nd line